# Use azure event hub to design a streaming integration solution

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

need some ideas here, on how to use azure event hub to design a 'kafka' like integration solution.

background,
have a event producer, which will spit a event call a webhook. on the consumer side, have a 'fast' consumer which needs to receive those events in real time, and another 'slow' consumer which follows daily batch.

[solution in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTThg.png)

the goal for this is to build on serverless/event driven, but unsure this design is right..

Comment: Can real-time consumers ingest data directly from Event Hubs w/o needing a function in front of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH based on your text I am having difficulties to understand what you want to achieve. But based on your picture I can say the following:

- Between Event Hub and the Function you don't need an Event Grid (actually it wouldn't work like that). The Function listens directly to the Event Hub and gets new messages from it.
- Between the Event Hub and the SQL Database I would put an Azure Stream Analytics job. Easiest way to get that job done. Alternatively you could also use another Azure Function there.

Comment: thanks for the comments, great advice. Is there a better pattern to handle the use case of 'slow consumer' in the way the events from event hub need to staged somewhere then get processed later with a batch job?

Comment: Why not just keep them in event hub? They can stay there for up to 7 days. Every time you run the batch consumer it just gets all the events since it ran last

Comment: I see so the event hub can keep the messages while delivering the update to azure function which feeds to the real-time consumer

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you use different consumer groups. You can read each event as many times as you like as long as it is in the retention time